# KotlinJsr223JvmDaemonLocalEvalScriptEngineFactory KotlinCompileDaemon not started

Tags: maven, kotlin, jar, scriptengine

I’m trying to use the KotlinJsr223JvmDaemonLocalEvalScriptEngineFactory in the SpringBot application.
When trying to execute a script, I get

> javax.script.ScriptException: Unable to connect to repl server:
>       DEBUG starting the daemon as: C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jre1.8.0_172 \ bin 
>       \ java -cp C: \ Users \ user \ projects \ lkb \ lkb \ target \ kotlin- 
>       compiler-1.3.10.jar -Djava .awt.headless = true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname = 
>       127.0.0.1 org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.KotlinCompileDaemon --daemon-r
>       unFilesPath C: \ Users \ user \ AppData \ Local \ kotlin \ daemon --daemon- 
>       autoshutdownIdleSeconds = 7200 --daemon-compilerClasspath C: \ Users \ user 
>       \ projects \ lkb \ lkb \ target \ kotlin-compiler-1.3.10. jar
>       INFO [daemon] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin / reflect / 
>       KDeclarationContainer

When i run it in IDE all fine. When i try it in command line java -jar i get this exception.

Please tell me what I’m doing wrong.
In the project I use
Kotlin 1.3.10
maven

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a dependency, and you need to add `kotlin-reflect` to your Maven configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm a bit confused: why are you using `java -jar` if you're using Maven. Don't do that, use `mvn spring-boot:run` instead.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the reply.
My pom has this dependency. I need the application to run from jar. I create a FAT JAR with the help of spring-maven plugin. And yes mvn spring-boot: run works ... this is how I tested it. and on the prod server run only through jar